# Как доделать динамическое меню на React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Есть такой код в Header.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import menuJson from './menu.json'


export class Header extends React.Component {


    render() {

        const menu = JSON.parse(menuJson);

        return (
            <ul className="navigation">
                //тут должны быть li'шки из menu
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

Никак не могу додумать, как добавить пункты из `menu` в `.navigation`.
Это menu.json :

```
{
  "home" : "#1",
  "pricing" : "#2",
  "about us" : "#3",
  "contact" : "#4"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартный `for .. in` справится с этой задачей.

```
import React from 'react';
import menuJson from './menu.json'

export class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const menu = JSON.parse(menuJson);

        let menuList = []
        for (let menuName in menu) {
            menuList.push(<li>{menuName}</li>);
        }

        return (
            <ul className="navigation">
                {menuList}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Супер!

menuList.push(<li>{menuName}</li>) - это JSX? В нативном JS не выйдет так вставлять элемент?

Comment: @NikitaShchypylov да, `return (...)` в вашем вопросе тоже JSX.

Comment: То есть, данную запись можно использовать везде, где хочу, когда мне нужен JSX?

Comment: @NikitaShchypylov Да, можно где угодно. Это после компиляции превратиться в обычный JS.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо!